# I want to see what profiles my page has viewed in the past

Tags: facebook

How can I see what profiles my page has viewed?  I found how to see what videos were viewed, but would like to see the profiles.

Comment: Don't think that's possible

Answer (score 1):

You can't. [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/210896588933875) doesn't let people track who views their profile. Third-party apps also can't provide this functionality. If you come across an app that claims to offer this ability, please [report the app](https://www.facebook.com/help/117257561692875?helpref=faq_content).